# Fear of DAD and leaving

Tags: behavior, communication, crying, fears, moving

I'm 26 years but i still stay with my Dad because in a typical african home its a taboo for a lady to leave her fathers and live alone. They see it as her being wayward and she will not have chances to marry...

My older ones didn't move out before they got married but it was living hell because we bottled up a lot of anger from verbal abuse and hate speech from my Dad, but he keeps saying he loves us and he wants us to do better. He is very difficult, very demanding and expects everything should be done in his favour and when its not he becomes manipulative, threatens to destroy one who tries anything otherwise.

Right now, I'm tired of living in the house with him because these things are eating me really deep and I don't want to say words I don't mean out of anger. I want to move out but don't know how to do it because he would call family meetings and cause trouble. Sometimes he would twist situations in his favour so the extended family would believe him ...

Honestly I'M TIRED and i want out i don't know how to go about it...

I work and financially stable enough to afford a good rent, He doesn't pay any bills for me but i stay in the house out of respect for the family and everyone.

Please I need your honest advice, what should i do?!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  Unfortunately this isn't really an answerable question, and isn't really about parenting, so isn't on topic. I'd encourage you to seek help from those close to you outside of your family, and from available resources in your community for youths in trouble.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you live with an aunt or grandmother or older sister?